# Create a 1:1 Master-Detail Relationship using validation rules

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to create a 1:1 Relationship with an object. Where they will exist in the child object only once to prevent duplication of the same master objects entry in the detail table. Is there a validation rule i can use to do this? or am i forced to use a trigger.

For eg.

Parent_*c.Name, can only exist ONCE in the Child*_c, so each Child_*c.Parent*_r.Name will have a unique value. Is there anyway to achieve this via the validation rules or filter a lookup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create new roll-up field (for counting child records) and validation rule which said that value in this field can't be > 1.
Thanks to that you will get 1-to-1 relationship